# VueのLintでautofixされない

Tags: vue.js, eslint

Vue.js 2.6で、cliで自動生成したプロジェクトのlintを実行したのですが、エラーが出力されるだけでfixされません。

例えば、デフォルトではインデントは2 spacesとなっていますが、
`.eslintrc.js`の`rules`で`"vue/script-indent": ["error", 4]`と設定して再度
`vue-cli-service lint`を実行すると

```
error: Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2 spaces (vue/script-indent) at src/components/HelloWorld.vue:141:1:
  139 |       }
  140 |     ]
> 141 |   })
      | ^
  142 | });
  143 | </script>
  144 |


59 errors found.
59 errors potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

と返され、`--fix`をつけろと言うことですが、そのようなオプションをつけても無視されてしまいます。

[cli-plugin-eslintのgithub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-eslint)のReadmeを見る限り、そもそも`vue-cli-service lint`はデフォルトでfixもされるようです。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　私の環境で以下の手順で試してみたのですが、auto fix が走るようでした。vue 2.6.11、@vue/cli-service 4.5.0 です。おそらく質問者さんの手順と差分があると思うので、質問者さんの手順を質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。以下手順です。(1) `vue create hello-world` で Vue 2.x を指定してプロジェクト作成 (2) `cd hello-world` (3) package.json の eslintConfig の rules に `"vue/script-indent": ["error", 2]` を追加 (4) `npm run lint` (内部的には `vue-cli-service lint`) をすると auto fix されました。

Comment: 御丁寧にありがとうございます。たった今確認したところ、 `"vue/script-indent": ["error", 2]`で、例えばインデントを4 spacesにしてあるところがautofixされたことを確認しました。しかし個人的なこだわりでインデントルールを 4 spacesにしたく、 `"vue/script-indent": ["error", 4]`とすると、質問文の通り、autofixされないままです。バージョンは@vue/cli 4.5.11で、autofix自体は正常な動きをすることがわかったのでよかったです。　ありがとうございます

Comment: あれ、私の環境だと `"vue/script-indent": ["error", 4]` でも autofix されますね……。やはり質問者さんの環境と差分があるようなので、質問文に詳しい手順を書いていただけないでしょうか。